# Message Queueing Architecture

Tags: architecture, message-queue

I'm trying to modify an existing workflow described below to be asynchronous using message queueing.

1. User requests a set of data records to export in a web app
2. A request is sent to an Export API endpoint which triggers a sequence of service calls based on records selected
3. The response of the service calls are combined and groomed into a format needed for export.
4. Another service call is made to a File Generation API to build the excel file
5. The results of step 4 are returned to the client

This process does not scale well since the client has to wait for steps 1-5 to complete before leaving the page. In addition, depending on the number of records selected in step 1, the process can time out due to network limitations.

In my mind, every record selected in step 1 should be fetched separately using a combination of a message queue and some worker processes interacting with the queue. However, this introduces a dependency between messages because the request cant be fully "completed" until all the records have been fetched, which seems like a wrong way to go.

Alternatively, having a single worker process that handles fetching all records in step 1 seems bad because there is no way to "scale out" this workload. So if a user selects 1000 records, the executing process needs to handle all 1000 records so the performance would seem on par with the workflow described above in steps 1-5.

Comment: Take a look at temporal.io.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

The easiest way to implement *asynchronous* processing is to adopt the *trasaction* approach where the process is split into a *Request* and a separate method to check the *State* or status of the *transaction* that was created in this initial *Request*.

The API responds to a request with a *token* that represents the *transaction*. That request will also spawn off any background processing or message queue logic.

The client must call the API to check the *State* (status) of the *transaction* and retrieve the result when/if is is ready.

Common patterns in *async transactions* may involve other method calls to retrieve processing logs, or to cancel the pending request.

This *Transaction* model is most simply experienced in online financial transactions through 3rd party payment providers.

[image: Asynchronous Messaging API workflow] source: https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2017/05/09/patterns-of-soa-asynchronous-transaction/

---

### Original Post:

One solution, if the per-row processing can be written into batches or can be executed in parallel is to recognise that there are multiple levels of Tasks here:

1. the Export *Request* Task
2. individual data preparation activities
3. the Export *Processing* or *Result* task
4. Notify the user that there is a response ready

   - or user can poll for state on the original *Request*

Depending on the frequency and concurrency of requests, as in how many of these *Export Requests* need to be serviced at the same time, you could use 2 queues, one to process individual records, and another to aggregate the results.

> This post [Patterns of SOA: Asynchronous Transaction](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2017/05/09/patterns-of-soa-asynchronous-transaction/) has some useful diagrams and background on the concept

The call to *step 1* should create a *Transaction Header* record for this task in a table or some other persistence storage. This *header* might include a count of all the records (or batches), a zero processed record counter and a primary reference key.
Then the API will add a message into a queue for each record (or batch) that needs to be exported, this message should include a reference to the *header*

- The response from the API should be (or include) the reference to this header.

The queue processes each record as required, then updates the *header* to reflect the process count.

- If your queuing technology does not support aggregation of results, you will also need to store the result for this single processed record somewhere, perhaps linked or attached to the *transaction header*

If the process count indicates that all records are completed, a message should be added to an additional queue to process the batch of results.

This queue will aggregate the results of the individual items and prepare the final output, this will in turn be linked or attached to the *transaction header* and the state updated in this *header* record.

- Use push methodology (and or email) to inform the client that the export request has been processed and is ready to be received.

---

This methodology means that we do not have to poll to determine completeness, however it does require a storage medium and will involve a lookup for the header record for each process. It also requires your queue handler to be able to aggregate results or for your queue processor to store the results somewhere.

The reason we do not try to make the first queue processor also manage the final step of combining the results and sending the export is that it has a different resource utilisation profile and may itself fail and need to be re-tried. We move that workload to it's own queue to take this into consideration.

The last step will be to notify the user that the export file is ready, if you do not have a PUSH mechanism, the client could periodically lookup (poll) the header to determine the state. In general a lookup query to check the state of a flag can easily be optimised to have minimal overall impact if PUSH is not an option.

---

Apart from the traditional shopping cart 3rd party processing model you might have experienced, another commercial example of this is in MS Office 365 Exchange Mail Trace report exports.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/monitoring/trace-an-email-message/run-a-message-trace-and-view-results

The user creates a request, and can specify an email to receive the fulfilment notification. When the export is ready an email will be sent, when the page is refreshed the current state of the request is refreshed, if the request is fulfilled, the user can download the export file.

- A nice touch is that the notification email is itself on a delay queue, so if the user accessed the file through the UI, the notification email is not sent.

---

This might be overkill, but is designed for extreme scale-out. Depending on your technology stack and chosen vendor, there may be OOTB solutions that abstract a lot of this away from you.

[MS Azure Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) provides a reliable way to abstract aways all these *queue* and message processing, aggregation and trigger concepts into a single manageable workflow, it is designed specifically to simplify the code required to achieve a high level of scalability for problems like this.

Comment: Wow, thanks for writing this up, lots of good detail. I’ll need some time to digest this so let me get back to you.

Comment: @user95488 I've updated with a summary and a link to an external resource that probably does a better job than my initial brain fart.